# Determine width of div based on sibling width

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div/>`s arranged in a "column A" and "column B" fashion.  Column B is a set width, and i would like Column A to take up the remaining space.  Is there a way to achieve this in CSS?  Or maybe a better alternative to what I am doing?

This is the structure:

```
<div>
  <div id='colA'>style is float right</div>
  <div id='colB'>this has a set width of 50px</div>
<div>
```

Comment: why not fix width of one div and let the other one take remaining width you dont even need to do anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to keep two div side by side if the second has a long text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383299/how-to-keep-two-div-side-by-side-if-the-second-has-a-long-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `float` on one of them and add margin to the other that equals the width of the floated in that direction ..

```
<div>
  <div id='colA'>this has a set width of 50px and is floated</div>
  <div id='colB'>style has margin equal to floated width</div>
</div>
```

and

```
#colA {
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
#colB {
    margnin-left:50px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/C3caq/1/

Comment: I guess the OP wants a fixed width column on the right and have the left div taking up the remaining space.

Comment: @Antony, the OP can just change the float and margin direction to `right` as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/C3caq/2/

Comment: I liked Antony's answer, but for some reason the table display threw off the rest of my CSS.  So I went with this solution.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli what if we don't know or not setting the width of #colA before hand? I have a left div where I'm putting translated text, so the width of left div is dependent on the translated text.

Answer (score 5):

Use `display: table-cell`.

```css
#container{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#colA {
    display: table-cell;
}

#colB {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/urnur/5/).

Comment: toooo quick for me :) But i suggest you to propose an whole table like construction set ( table > tr > td ) .. see : http://jsfiddle.net/sPm9M/2/  inspired from another answer of mine here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627332/layout-with-divs-instead-of-table/15638656#15638656

Comment: @MilchePatern Yes, it would be better to have another div for `table-row`, even though most modern browsers would do just fine without it.